# Fazer join usando uma substring

Tags: postgresql

Como fazer join em duas tabelas verificando se uma string contém outra? Ex:

Na tabela A eu tenho o campo: `AAA;BBB;CCC` e na tabela B eu tenho o campo `BBB`.

Como fazer um join assim:

`select * from A join B on A.campo contem string B.campo`

Comment: `like '%'|| B.campo || '%'` ?

Answer (score 0):

Essa forma de relacionamento não é recomendado, melhor seria com chave estrangeira normalizada, sendo um id numérico e único. Mas poderia tentar colocar um like

Em vez do join use união simples:

```
select * from a, b
where a.campo like '%'|| B.campo || '%'
```

Comment: ERRO:  operador não existe: record ~~ text
LINE 4: where a."DOC" like '%'|| b.nu_cns || '%'
HINT:  Nenhum operador corresponde com o nome e o(s) tipo(s) de argumento(s) informados. Você precisa adicionar conversões de tipo explícitas.

Comment: os tipos dos campos sao diferente? tenta cast(a.campo as varchar) like '%'|| cast(B.campo as varchar) || '%'

Comment: `a."DOC"` é efetivamente um nome de campo da tabela `a`? A mensagem de erro informa que não, que `a."DOC"` é um pseudo type do tipo `record`.